# Why can I not load arrays from RoamingSettings?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, c++-cx

The initial target was to store a colour in the `ApplicationData::Current->RoamingSettings`, but as the Values container is an `IPropertySet`, I am limited in the types I can store.

So, I am using a `Array<unsigned char, 1U>^` to store the RGBA-values like so:

```
ApplicationDataContainer^ roamingSettings = ApplicationData::Current->RoamingSettings;
Color black = Colors::Black;
Array<unsigned char, 1U>^ rgbaIn = ref new Array<unsigned char, 1U>{ black.R, black.G, black.B, black.A };
roamingSettings->Values->Insert("colourArr", PropertyValue::CreateUInt8Array(rgbaIn));
//String for control reasons
roamingSettings->Values->Insert("colourStr", PropertyValue::CreateString(ref new String(L"black")));

Array<unsigned char, 1U>^ rgbaOut = dynamic_cast<Array<unsigned char, 1U>^>(roamingSettings->Values->Lookup("colourArr"));
String^ colour = dynamic_cast<String^>(roamingSettings->Values->Lookup("colourStr"));
```

At this point, `rgbaOut` is an *empty* array, while `colour` has the correct value of `"black"`.

*Why? And what can I do to work around this?*

---

I should probably mention that `rgbaIn` is correctly constructed and does indeed contain the correct four values.

Comment: I don't believe it can actually process arrays, or if it does it's not serializing it properly. If you want to use an array, I suggest serializing it and deserializing it manually before putting it into the settings.

Comment: Yeah, that's my current workaround: Just putting the RGBA-values into a String and saving that. Works like a charm.